# How to use or logic tests outside capture groups in tidyr::extract

Tags: regex, r, tidyr

I need a way to use 'Or' statements with entire words outside capture groups in tidyr::extract, like in the next example.

Suppose i have the next strings:

```
string1 <- data.frame (col = "asdnajksdn**thingA**asdnaksjdnajksn")
string2 <- data.frame (col = "asdnajksdn**itemA**asdnaksjdnajksn")
```

i want to use tidyr::extract() to extract 'A' and 'B' with the same regular expressions, but i DONT want to extract 'word' or 'thing', the desired output would be:

```
string1 %>% extract(col = 'col', regex = regex, into = "var")
> NewColumn
  "A"

string2 %>% extract(col = 'col', regex = regex, into = "NewColumn")
> NewColumn
  "B"
```

The answer would be something like that:

```
extract(string, col = "col", into = "NewColumn",
        regex = "(word)|(thing)(.)")
```

But i can't do that because it would result in:

```
NewColumn NA
word      A
```

I know that in the example i could just use something like

```
"[ti][ht][ie][nm]g?(.)"
```

but i'm looking for a more general solution.

Comment: is `**` exists in your input?

Comment: Try `string1 <- data.frame (col = "asdnajksdnthingAasdnaksjdnajksn")` and then `string1 %>% extract(col, c("NewColumn"), "(?:word|thing)(.)")`. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since *tidyr* `extract()` extracts the *capturing group* values, you can group the alternatives that you do not want to extract with a [*non-capturing* group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group).

The syntax of a [**non-capturing group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) is `(?:...)`:

> If you do not need the group to capture its match, you can optimize this regular expression into `Set(?:Value)?`. The question mark and the colon after the opening parenthesis are the syntax that creates a non-capturing group. The question mark after the opening bracket is unrelated to the question mark at the end of the regex.

So, use something  like:

```
> library(tidyr)
> string1 <- data.frame (col = "asdnajksdnthingAasdnaksjdnajksn")
> string1 %>% extract(col, c("NewColumn"), "(?:word|thing)(.)")
  NewColumn
1         A
```